# createjs hitTest works just on moving without hitting the object

Tags: actionscript-3, createjs

when i touch the circle to the rect then alpha should be 0.1
but unfortunately alpha becomes 0.1 once i move circle   . perhaps its happening for upF(e) . but i tried to keeping bold code inside all function and even outside the scope . but nothing worked.i have uploaded here
http://graphicscoder.org/stackover/hit/hittest.html

```
/* js 

var t1 = this;
t1.circle.addEventListener('mousedown', downF)
function downF(e) {
stage.addEventListener('stagemousemove', moveF);
stage.addEventListener('stagemouseup', upF);
};

function upF(e) {

    var pt = t1.globalToLocal(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
if (t2.hitTest(pt.x, pt.y)) {
  t1.alpha=0.1;
}
  stage.removeAllEventListeners();
}
function moveF(e) {
t1.circle.x = stage.mouseX;
t1.circle.y = stage.mouseY;
}


// to move a rect here is the code
var t2 = this;
t2.rect.addEventListener('mousedown', downFr)

function downFr(e) {
stage.addEventListener('stagemousemove', moveFr);
stage.addEventListener('stagemouseup', upFr);
};
function upFr(e) {
stage.removeAllEventListeners();
}
function moveFr(e) {
t2.rect.x = stage.mouseX;
t2.rect.y = stage.mouseY;
}

*/
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the pressmove event on your objects?

Comment: no reason but i am a new coder . so what the code will be ? where to use pressmove ? thanks

Comment: The pressmove event fires any time you press on an item, and then drag your mouse, until your release the mouse. Check out the drag and drop demo in GitHub (you can see it live here, and edit the code online: http://www.createjs.com/demos/easeljs/draganddrop)